# Why use a statement inside an "if" statement?

Tags: if-statement, go

The [Go tour](http://tour.golang.org/#23) shows an example where they have an extra statement in the same line as the "if" statement and they explain it like this: `the if statement can start with a short statement to execute before the condition.`

```
func pow(x, n, lim float64) float64 {
    if v := math.Pow(x, n); v < lim {
        return v
    }
    return lim
}
```

I don't see the need for this syntax and find it very confusing. Why not just write `v := math.Pow(x, n)` in the previous line?

The reason I'm asking is that for what I'm finding out, syntax finds its way into the Go language after careful consideration and nothing seems to be there out of whim.

I guess my actual question would be: What specific problem are they trying to solve by using this syntax? What do you gain by using it that you didn't have before?

Comment: Scope?  Is `v` still in scope after the close brace `}` and before `return lim`?  I expect not, and that would be why it is written thus.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There are many use cases and I do not think this feature tackles a specific problem but is rather a pragmatic solution for some problems you encounter when you code in Go. The basic intentions behind the syntax are:

- proper scoping: Give a variable only the scope that it needs to have
- proper semantics: Make it clear that a variable only belongs to a specific conditional part of the code

Some examples that I remember off the top of my head:

**Limited scopes**:

```
if v := computeStuff(); v == expectedResult {
    return v
} else {
    // v is valid here as well
}

// carry on without bothering about v
```

**Error checking**:

```
if perr, ok := err.(*os.PathError); ok {
    // handle path error specifically
}
```

or more general, **Type checking**:

```
if someStruct, ok := someInterface.(*SomeStruct); ok {
    // someInterface is actually a *SomeStruct.
}
```

**Key checking in maps**:

```
if _, ok := myMap[someKey]; ok {
    // key exists
}
```

Comment: That type assertion with `ok` flag is cool! Haven't seen much of that.

Comment: @SimonWhitehead That's a pity because you should always check type assertions :)

Comment: Granted I haven't been playing with Go for very long, so my exposure to it written by other people is fairly limited :) That might explain to a few of the regulars around here why I leave such excited comments! :D

Comment: Probably also because they realized the C construct of `if (s = getChar())` is very useful, bul also kind of evil and doesn't work well with multiple return values.

Answer (score 3):

Because so your variables are contained in the scope
Notice that those `v` are declared on different scope.

A more direct example to understand scopes: http://play.golang.org/p/fInnIkG5EH

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
)

func main() {
    var hello = "Hello"

    {
        hello := "This is another one"
        fmt.Println(hello)
    }

    if hello := "New Hello"; hello != ""{
       fmt.Println(hello)
    }

    fmt.Println(hello)
}
```